# TOR Hidden Service: IP anonymity

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, relays, ip-address

Suppose that a Tor client wants to access a certain hidden service. According to the protocol, instead of submitting a request directly to the server IP (which is hidden<sup>[1][2]</sup>), this client submit a request via a series of relays.

However, at some point, there will be a final relay in charge of delivering the client's message specifically to the server running the hidden service. In order to do so, this final relay must know the IP of this hidden server, otherwise the current internet infrastructure cannot deliver the message.

If the aforementioned steps are indeed correct, this means that in order to host a website using TOR Hidden Service you must reveal the IP address to a final relay. Therefore, Tor network does not hide the IP address of hidden services.

How to reconcile that? Am I missing something?

---

[1]: "TOR Hidden Service allows you to host a website, without revealing where the website is, and hence protects the identity of the publisher/webmaster.", [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/How_to_Protect_your_Internet_Anonymity_and_Privacy/TOR_Hidden_Service_for_Anonymous_Websites)

[2]: "The Tor network hides the IP address of hidden services, instead using onion addresses and public keys to keep the real location hidden.", [Privay.net](https://privacy.net/make-site-visible-dark-web-tor-hidden-services/)

Answer (score 0):

Tor uses TCP tunnels, so - regardless of the previous answer - no need to use it. The hidden service is reached from the Tor node that is hosting it, usually through a localhost. The scenario you've described about IP revealing - yes, it *can* be a privacy problem. The design doc states clear - the system is anonymizing mostly the client, not the server - it's only rudimentary in a *standard* setup. To conceal your server IP use bridges-only for your hosting server(s) - that will elevate the privacy, but if you want both client and server to be equally anonymized - use I2P, not Tor - it's designed for exactly that purpose

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a simplistic explanation, but I hope it helps.

The Tor service, running on the machine where the onion service is being hosted, reaches out to the Tor Network and says, if you want to use onion abcxyz.onion or port 80, then you have to talk to me (the service) but not to the IP of the machine. Because the connection is originated from the machine being hosted and not from an external machine, no actual IP is needed to be shared.

To look at it another way.

I set up a web server on standard TCP port 80
I make sure that my firewall is closed on TCP port 80 so nobody can connect to that web server. (sounds pointless, right?)
I then tell the Tor service to advertise that web server on Tor so people can view it. 
You say, "but wait you have a firewall up, they won't be able to see your web sserver!"
That would be true if I was expecting external users to connect to me.
Instead, the Tor service connected to the Tor Network via UDP (not TCP) and other people are able to use that connection to come in and view my web server even with the firewall turned on.
Nobody ever sees my IP because that UDP connection from my web server to the Tor network doesn't contain TCP/IP informatation. It just contains an address and a connection to get in.

Comment: > _"if you want to use onion abcxyz.onion or port 80, then you have to talk to me (the service) but not to the IP of the machine"_ The only way a node can communicate with you using the current internet infrastructure is by knowing your IP address. Without your IP address, you will never receive any income message. Mind to explain that?

Comment: Tor isn't the current internet infrastructure.  Tor is an overlay network that uses UDP.

> Without your IP address, you will never receive any income message.

That's because you don't get incoming TCP connections like you do with the Internet.  People who want to visit your onion service use the connection that your local Tor service made to Tor.  It is almost the opposite of how we normally think about how clients and servers work.

Comment: One more example: My ISP only gives me an internal 192.168 IP. They don't give me a real IP of my own. The real IP is shared with dozens of other people (it sucks, I know). How do users find my onion service if traffic can't come to me on a real IP? By coming in over my existing connection to Tor.

Comment: > _"Tor isn't the current internet infrastructure."_ Ok, Tor is not the current internet infrastructure. The current internet infrastructure encompass several devices that, among other things, uses the OSI model. Considering such model, Tor is implemented in the application layer. Therefore it uses the services below it (mainly, the network layer), which requires an IP address for communication. It is simply not possible to submit internet packets without an IP address. Routers simply wouldn't know where to forward such packet.

Comment: > _"Tor is an overlay network that uses UDP."_ UDP (transport layer) requires an IP address. Without an IP address you simply can not submit an UDP packet.

Comment: > _"People who want to visit your onion service use the connection that your local Tor service made to Tor."_ Mind to explain that? AFAIK, at some point one of the Tor nodes will communicate with your server requesting something from your hidden service. Please, correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: > _"My ISP only gives me an internal 192.168 IP."_ This is your internal IP, not your external IP. Your ISP must provide you with an external IP otherwise you won't be able to browse the net. However, there are some gimmicks to let one single IP address be used by multiple users (take a look at CGNAT). However, if your ISP is using CGNAT, you won't be able to host services.

Comment: Type 'my ip' at google to know your external IP address. You **MUST** have one !!!

Comment: Here is the official onion service page: https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services.html.en.  It's still a bit watered down. I will also see if I can find one or more academic papers that going into more details.

Comment: https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.pdf

Comment: https://www.onion-router.net/Publications/or-iomodel.pdf

Comment: I'm gonna take a while to read all that, especially the design paper. However, I already got suspicious early at the beginning of the official page: "the green links are circuits rather than direct connections. By using a full Tor circuit, it's hard for anyone to associate an introduction point with the onion server's IP address." Therefore, if a Tor circuit doesn't use IP address how does it send packets to the internet? Mac address?

Comment: Tor uses TCP only, so no UDP here